# Drupal to Drupal migration of url alias

Tags: 7, migrations

How can I do a Drupal to Drupal migrate that includes the migration of the "url alias"?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the d2d_migrate automatically handles it for you.

Comment: I needed to add migrate extras for it to work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name (on both source and destination sides) for path aliases is 'path'. As Jaypan says, migrate_d2d should be mapping that for you by default.